# Range validation where value is with comma and not with dot

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use a range validator:

```
[Range(typeof(Decimal), "0.1", "9999",
 ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
```

but I am using `DecimalModelBinder` so decimal value now uses a comma instead of a period (dot).

So `2,5` is now valid and not `2.5`

I want to to use the range between 0.1 and 9999.

I am getting the error:

> 0.1 is not a valid value for Decimal.

EDIT:

I am using this culture settings in web.xml

```
<system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8"
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
           uiCulture="sl-SI" 
           culture="sl-SI" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: What CultureInfo do you have your current thread set to? Some cultures use comma's instead of decimals.

Comment: Is the validation error happening on the client or the server?

Answer (score 0):

It goes off of your current culture setting. 
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator

Your current culture SL uses "," as the decimal separator. If you used a culture like en-US if would take "." as valid.

Make sure your current thread culture is set to SL, can be checked with the code above.

Also, I am not sure if it matters, but the docs say that the compare type should be double, not decimal.

Comment: Yes I want comma as a valid separator not dot.